# Android Device informations

Tags: android, device

How can I retrieve Android devices informations (such as screen size, density, OS version, etc.) from the PC (with adb for example) ?

Answer (score 0):

I think the `dumpsys`-command could be what you're searching for, check the [Shell-Commands](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html#shellcommands) section of the [adb-Manual](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html).

Comment: I only find Dump window log wich displays : mDisplayWidth=600 mDisplayHeight=1024. Is it reliable ? for all devices ?

Comment: Ther is a command namend `dumpsys`, the description says: "Dumps system data to the screen". But it also says that the [DDMS](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debugging/ddms.html) also prints those things out, so you might want to use it.